# MIUI Android crash on SMS reception with listener active

Tags: android, sms

I'm currently testing an app on an HD2 equipped with MIUI (Gingerbread 2.3.7). I instantiate a BroadcastReceiver to intercept incoming SMS and register it. After a couple of seconds, MIUI crashes to boot animation.

The phone is dual-booting between WM6.5 and Android. I have no other Android phone to test. From my experiments, the crash occurs when the phone receives the SMS I'm waiting for. **No log message warns me about the crash, no single line of the BroadcastReceiver is executed**.

Here's how I set up the listener

```
    try {
        smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver();
        IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        iFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver, iFilter);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        Log.e("MyActivity", "Error");
        throw ex;
    }
```

Manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name="SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="300" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The code doesn't hit the catch block. My app has already the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission in the manifest.

How could I fix it? My app fully relies on SMS parsing.

Comment: I'm starting to think that it's a MIUI bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known MIUI bug ([source](http://techietalkz.com/2011/06/14/how-to-solve-the-new-miui-android-rom-1-6-reboot-issues/), [source](http://miuiandroid.com/community/threads/1-6-3-phone-reboot-on-sms-recived.7149/)).

Changing Android distribution solved my problem. I received SMS without problems and I also found that the manifest doesn't need to be updated when you programmatically define a `BroadcastReceiver`